# UWP determine if TextBlock is trimmed by MaxLines or TextTrimming properties?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Could you tell how I can determine if TextBlock control is trimmed (not by Actual&Desired sizes) by MaxLines or/and TextTrimming properties?

I want to have TB property('s) like a `"IsTrimmed"` or `"ActualLines"` and `"IsTextTrimmed`" - these properties can show me if the TextBlock render less content that I have to show button, e.g. `"Show all..."` / `"Show more..."`.